# How to release a dataframe in spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am using spark do some calculation. every 5 minutes, I got a new data frame. I put it into a dict called dict_1_hour like this

```
dict_1_hour[timestamp] = dataframe
```

New data frame comes in to the dict and old dataframe pop out from the dict. Only 12 dataframe are kept in it, that is the data for the recent 1 hour.

So my question is how should I release those dataframe to make sure there is no memory leak?

One API for dataframe seems can do it.(I do not know what the parameter for)

```
unpersist(blocking=True)
Marks the DataFrame as non-persistent, and remove all blocks for it from memory and disk.
```

The other way I think is just pop the dataframe from the dict.

```
dict_1_hour.pop(timestamp)
```

Python should auto release the unused variable. But I do not know if it is appropriate here. I worried that spark may keep the dataframe if you do not release it explicit

So please advice on which way I should use please

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak? Python is garbage-collected and is generally very good at managing memory for you.

Comment: Actually there do have a memory leak now. The memory leak caused the Spark Driver program stop @Akshat Mahajan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all `DataFrame`, similar to `RDD`, is just a local recursive data structure. I goes through the same garbage collection cycle as any other object, both on the Python and JVM side.

The second part you have to consider is persisted data (`cache`, `persist`, `cacheTable`, shuffle files, etc.). This in general handled internally by Spark and, excluding `unpersist` you don't much control  over its lifetime.

Keeping these two things in mind there is not much that can be done beyond simple `del` on the object.

```
try:
    del dict_1_hour[timestamp]
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Still, if `DataFrame` has been registered as temporary table, make sure to unregister it first:

```
from py4j.protocol import Py4JError

try:
    sqlContext.dropTempTable("df")
except Py4JError:
    pass
```

Comment: what is the difference between these 3 ways?  1.  del dict_1_hour[timestamp]     2. dict_1_hour[timestamp].unpersist    3. dict_1_hour.pop(timestamp)   can we say they both released the memory? (for the pop method. I am sure that there is nowhere else using the dataframe once it is pop)

Comment: Actually none of these really releases the memory. What `del` or (`del()`), which is not covered by simple `pop`, is to call `__del__` method which can be used to release external resources (to be clear `DataFrame` inherits default implementation from `object` so there is nothing interesting going on there).

Comment: then what about unpersist? I am guesting that if we did not use cache/persist to explicitly keep the data frame, then we do not need to call unpersist, right?

Comment: You're right, and even if you did it should be cleared automatically.